# Group key value objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an array of objects (pre_finalTab_new below) like this:

[image]

My goal is to group them by "schema", and then by "tip" and insert into new array, something like this:

```
 var celotnaTabela = {};
 for (var nov in pre_finalTab_new)
  {
      var shema = pre_finalTab_new[nov].schema.trim();
      var objekt_tip = pre_finalTab_new[nov].type.trim();
      var objekt_name = pre_finalTab_new[nov].name.trim();
      var tip =  pre_finalTab_new[nov].tip.trim();
 
      if (celotnaTabela[shema] === undefined)
      {
          celotnaTabela[shema] = [];
          if (celotnaTabela[shema][tip] === undefined)
          {
              celotnaTabela[shema][tip] = [];
              if (celotnaTabela[shema][tip][objekt_tip] === undefined)
              {
                  celotnaTabela[shema][tip][objekt_tip] = [];
                  celotnaTabela[shema][tip][objekt_tip] = [objekt_name];
 
              } else
                  celotnaTabela[shema][tip][objekt_tip].push(objekt_name);
          }
      } else
      {
          if (celotnaTabela[shema][tip] === undefined)
          {
              celotnaTabela[shema][tip] = [];
          }
          if (celotnaTabela[shema][tip][objekt_tip] === undefined)
          {
              celotnaTabela[shema][tip][objekt_tip] = [];
              celotnaTabela[shema][tip][objekt_tip] = [objekt_name];
 
          } else
          {
              if (!celotnaTabela[shema][tip][objekt_tip].includes(objekt_name))
                  celotnaTabela[shema][tip][objekt_tip].push(objekt_name);
          }
 
      }
  }
```

Then if i output celotnaTabela, i got this:

[image]

Expanded:

[image]

Even more:

[image]

But the problem is, when i try to use JSON.stringify(celotnaTabela), i got this:

```json
{"HR":[],"ZOKI":[]}
```

But i need it to be in a right format, so i can pass this object into AJAX call..

Can anyone help me with this, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: could you show the result you want?

Comment: @Frenchy i would like same result as shown in "expanded" picture, but in JSON format..so the JSON.stringify would work "normal"

Comment: Change `celotnaTabela[shema] = []` to `celotnaTabela[shema] = {}` and everywhere else you use `= []` to `= {}`.  You're creating an array, but not `.push`ing values into it, instead adding them directly with a key; these don't stringify well (as you've found).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i hope i understood everything right you asked for.
Next time provide the testdata and the wished result in textform pls.

```js
var obj = [
    { schema: "HR", type: " PACKAGE", name: "PAKET1", tip: "new_objects" },
    { schema: "HR", type: " PACKAGE", name: "PAKET2", tip: "new_objects" },
    { schema: "HR", type: " PROCEDURE", name: "ADD_JOB_HISTORY", tip: "new_objects" },
    { schema: "ZOKI", type: " TABLE", name: "TABELA2", tip: "new_objects" },
    { schema: "ZOKI", type: " TABLE", name: "TABELA3", tip: "new_objects" },
];

var out = {};
for (var i = 0, v; v = obj[i]; i++) {
    var a = v.schema.trim();
    var b = v.type.trim();
    var c = v.tip.trim();
    var d = v.name.trim();
    if (!out.hasOwnProperty(a)) {
        out[a] = {};
    }
    if (!out[a].hasOwnProperty(b)) {
        out[a][b] = {};
    }
    if (!out[a][b].hasOwnProperty(c)) {
        out[a][b][c] = []
    }
    out[a][b][c].push(d);
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(out, null, 2));
```

Comment: thank you very much! this works! :) i needed to replace var "b" with var "c", so instead of HR->package->new_objects i get HR->new_objects->package, but anyway, thank you for your help! :)